# Flipped view in RTCView for react-native

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I am using react-native-webrtc library for developing an application for video chat. When I local stream my video it displayed me flipped view of video in RTCView element.

Is there any argument I should have to pass with rtcview element? how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass mirror option.

```
<RTCView streamURL={this.state.stream.toURL()} mirror={true} />
```

Please check [react-native-webrtc github repo](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc#rtcview)